# TextAngular and Rangy classes and ids

Tags: angularjs, rangy, textangular

For this text

```
something something something
new line new line new line
```

textAngular generates the following html:

```
<p>something something something<br/>new line new line new line<br/></p>
```

But if I select text from both rows and apply something on it, the following html is generated:

```
<p>something <span id="selectionBoundary_1474901783760_9132792101106602" class="rangySelectionBoundary">&#65279;</span>something something<br/>new line new line<span id="selectionBoundary_1474901783759_6091248845512363" class="rangySelectionBoundary">&#65279;</span> new line<br/></p>
```

How can I disable this? It's fine if it doesn't apply anny style at all, I just want to get rid of those css classes and ids.